# Method [validate] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Method validate does not exit. I tried to validate my form values as shown in the figure. But it give me this error. Please tell me . I am new to laravel. 
[[image: User controller]

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried adding `use Validator;` to the top of your controller?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't extending the correct `Controller`.

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

`Controller` then extends `BaseController`.

If you open up `Controller` which resides in the same namespace as your other controllers, you will see it uses the trait `ValidatesRequests` which is what provides the `validate` method.

You can also remove the line `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`.  There should be no reason to import that.

Comment: Actually it is not working on my Laravel 5.4.36. I am extending the Controller for my RegisterController.